# How to make a high resolution mesh from RegionIntersection in 3D

Tags: graphics3d, finite-element-method, mesh, opencascade

I  want to make a high-resolution 3d model of the Reuleaux tetrahedron by using *Mathematica*

> The [Reuleaux tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_tetrahedron) is the intersection of four balls of radius s centered at the vertices of a regular tetrahedron with side length s.

```
p = {{0, 0, -(Sqrt[(3/2)]/2)}, {1/Sqrt[3], 0, 1/(2 Sqrt[6])},
    {-(1/(2 Sqrt[3])), 1/2, 1/(2 Sqrt[6])}, {-(1/(2 Sqrt[3])), -(1/2), 1/(2 Sqrt[6])}};

Graphics3D[{Red, Opacity[.4], Ball /@ p}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

```
reg = RegionIntersection @@ (Ball /@ p);
DiscretizeRegion[reg]
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Use the OpenCascadeLink for this:

```
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]
s = OpenCascadeShape /@ (Ball /@ p);
shape = OpenCascadeShapeIntersection[s];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[shape];
```

Or, even simpler:

```
shape = OpenCascadeShape[ RegionIntersection @@ (Ball /@ p)];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[shape];
```

Or:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[RegionIntersection @@ (Ball /@ p), 
  "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> {"OpenCascade"}]
```

You can then visualize with, for example:

```
groups = bmesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"];
temp = Most[Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[groups])]];
colors = ColorData["BrightBands"][#] & /@ temp;
bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm /@ colors]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

`DiscretizeRegion` before `RegionIntersection`.

```
p = {{0, 0, -(Sqrt[(3/2)]/2)}, {1/Sqrt[3], 0, 
    1/(2 Sqrt[6])}, {-(1/(2 Sqrt[3])), 1/2, 
    1/(2 Sqrt[6])}, {-(1/(2 Sqrt[3])), -(1/2), 1/(2 Sqrt[6])}};
reg = DiscretizeRegion /@ Ball /@ p
RegionIntersection[reg, ViewPoint -> {-1.14137, 0.973908, 0.865322}, 
 ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"]
```

[image]

Comment: `MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01,AccuracyGoal -> 3` Maybe useful.

Comment: +1 You can add the options `ViewPoint->{-1.14137, 0.973908, 0.865322}, ViewProjection->"Orthographic"` to the `RegionIntersection` and skip the `RegionPlot3D`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you! Just what I looking for!

Answer (score 1):

```
With[{p = {{0, 0, -(Sqrt[(3/2)]/2)}, {1/Sqrt[3], 0, 
                    1/(2 Sqrt[6])}, {-(1/(2 Sqrt[3])), 1/2, 
                    1/(2 Sqrt[6])}, {-(1/(2 Sqrt[3])), -(1/2), 1/(2 Sqrt[6])}}},
    RegionIntersection @@ (Ball /@ p) // 
        RegionPlot3D[#, PlotPoints -> 80] &
    ]
```

[image]